# Tool for extracting base class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

If I have a C# code like this:

```
public class A {
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }

    public string PropZ { get; set; }

}

public class B {
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }

    public string PropX { get; set; }
    public string PropY { get; set; }

}
```

As `PropA` and `PropB` exist in both class, and have the same meaning, I'd like to refactor like this :

```
public abstract class Base {
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base {
    public string PropZ { get; set; }

}
public class B : Base {

    public string PropX { get; set; }
    public string PropY { get; set; }

}
```

Using VS 2010, is there any tool/extension that allows me to quickly do that ?
In fact, my actual code contains dozens of property in several classes, not in the same order. This is can be a bit of pain to properly factorize the code... that's why I'm looking for a lazy way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Resharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper) with "Extract Superclass".

Comment: Resharper is commercial... maybe a free tool ? (Yes I know Resharper has other advantages that can justify its cost... but it's not the matter here)

Comment: Maybe [CodeRush Xpress](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2009/06/25/coderush-xpress-for-c-and-visual-basic-2008.aspx) also supports this. If it is a one time job, you could also just use the trial version of Resharper to get the job done

Comment: CodeRush does not provide this (I'm using CodeRush Xpress)

Comment: I've mark your answer. It does not match my requirements (free tool), but it is still an answer to the quesiton